# Excel Custom Data Validation Allows Invalid Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation

I am trying to write a custom validation formula to require the following conditions for Cell `O22` on a spreadsheet:

- Value must be a number
- Value cannot be zero
- Value must be greater than or equal to 0.001
- Value must be greater than the cell to the right

In the example, `O22` is the gross weight for an object and `P22` is the net weight, so both will be numbers.

So I plug in the following formula to a custom data validation box:

`=AND(ISNUMBER(O22), O22<>0, O22>0.001, O22>P22)`

However, when I go to enter in an invalid value such as the letter `"A"`, no error message appears. I can put the exact same formula into another cell and it will evaluate as `false`, because `"A"` is not a number.

After building the formula out one condition at a time, everything works correctly until I add the `O22>P22` test. This is when it starts accepting any value without error. Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: I used your validation formula and it correctly prevented me from entering invalid data.

Comment: It might help to try: =IF(ISNUMBER(O22),AND(O22<>0, O22>0.001, O22>P22),FALSE) to prevent numerical comparisons on non-numerical data.

Comment: Yeah this seems to work fine. Also the `022<>0` is redundant as you also state `022>0.001` which will test false if the value is zero. I would try @xidgel answer. That way you will know if the value is being stored an non-numerical which it probably is if its not working for you.

Comment: I tried @xidgel answer, but if P22 is blank, I can enter any value I want into O22 without any complaint from Excel. I tried adding `P22=""` to the AND function tests as well as trying this on a blank spreadsheet in case something was corrupted with the original, but no change. If P22 is empty, I can enter whatever value I want into O22. If P22 has a value, O22's data validation will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uncheck the `Ignore Blank` check box in the Data Validation dialog box. If `Ignore Blank` is checked, no data will be validated as long as a cell in your validation formula (in this case `P22`) is blank.

Once `Ignore Blank` is unchecked, any formula that returns `FALSE` will be considered Invalid Data.

Comment: That appears to work. I appreciate the rather simple solution and will now kick myself for not having tried that before now.